# Delayed Job - job cannot be created for non-persisted record after destroy object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

Rails 4 and delayed_job 4.1.2. I attempt to delay recalculation of overall rating after destroying a Review, but obviously because after destroying a review object there is no ID for the Review object. So every time after trying to destroy an object, it tries to create a delayed job but throws this error:

```
ArgumentError (job cannot be created for non-persisted record: 
#<Review id: 44, review: "Bad", rating: 1, reviewable_id: 2, 
reviewable_type: "Spot", user_id: 1, created_at: "2016-05-30 17:13:29", 
updated_at: "2016-05-30 17:13:29">):
  app/controllers/reviews_controller.rb:40:in `destroy'
```

I have the following code:

```
# reviews_controller.rb
class ReviewsController < ApplicationController
  def destroy
    review.destroy
    flash[:success] = t("reviews.destroy.success")
  end
end

# review.rb
class Review < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_destroy :calculate_overall_rating

  def calculate_overall_rating
    if number_of_reviews > 0
      reviewable.update_attribute(:overall_rating, overall_rating)
    else
      reviewable.update_attribute(:overall_rating, 0)
    end
  end
  handle_asynchronously :calculate_overall_rating
end
```

It's good to note that the `calculate_overall_rating` doesn't require a `Review` object.

If I remove `handle_asynchronously :calculate_overall_rating` it will work, and recalculate. But I am trying to delay this job.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This error is indeed [raised](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/blob/v4.1.2/lib/delayed/performable_method.rb#L8) by delayed_job when you try to delay a method on a deleted (or not yet created) record. The direct cause of this error is because delayed_job [passes `self`](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/blob/v4.1.2/lib/delayed/message_sending.rb#L15) (i.e. the just-deleted review object) as the target object when calling the`handle_asynchronously` method. I don't know why it behaves like that, I just found a [statement](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/issues/820) from one of the gem's authors that says it works the same way as ActiveJob.

Anyway, it seems to me that you might have the recalculation method defined in the wrong place. If I understand it correctly, after destroying a review, an average rating is recalculated based on all reviews of the given `reviewable` (e.g. a spot). It seems weird to me that such code is defined as a method of a single review *instance*. A single review (what's more a deleted one) should not know anything about other reviews of the same spot and should not have to deal with them at all.

I guess the **method should have been defined as a *class* method instead**, with the `reviewable` as a parameter. Of course this would mean you'd have to make the other calculation methods `overall_rating` and `number_of_reviews`, class methods, too. But I think this is a good thing, again, because the domain of these methods lies *outside* a single review. Something like the following:

```
# review.rb
class Review < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_destroy :recalculate_overall_rating

  def recalculate_overall_rating
    self.class.calculate_overall_rating(reviewable)
  end

  def self.calculate_overall_rating(reviewable)
    if number_of_reviews(reviewable) > 0
      reviewable.update_attribute(:overall_rating, overall_rating(reviewable))
    else
      reviewable.update_attribute(:overall_rating, 0)
    end
  end
  handle_asynchronously :calculate_overall_rating
end
```

Another option (and I like it even a bit more I guess) would be to place the recalculation methods **inside the reviewable class**, e.g. inside the `Post` class. If you have more reviewable class types, you could make a module included from all these classes, e.g. `Reviewable` (I hope that would not clash with the Rails association name though) and place the recalculation methods inside it, this time as *instance* methods. Why? Because it is an *instance* of a reviewable which wants to get all its reviews recalculated and which still exists even after a review deletion so it can be easily run asynchronously. Something like the following:

```
# reviewable.rb
module Reviewable
  def calculate_overall_rating
    if number_of_reviews > 0
      update_attribute(:overall_rating, overall_rating)
    else
      update_attribute(:overall_rating, 0)
    end
  end
  handle_asynchronously :calculate_overall_rating

  # overall_rating and number_of_reviews are also defined in this module
end

# review.rb
class Review < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_destroy :recalculate_overall_rating

  def recalculate_overall_rating
    reviewable.calculate_overall_rating
  end
end

# post.rb
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Reviewable
end
```